# Html Table view with vehicle selection and allocated time in php

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display html table with showing vehicles and allocated time for each vehicle

here is my table view

[image]

Here, user can select a vehicle for the date 21-06-2020. For that its showing list of vehicle with radio button and a time period from 8am to 7pm. Here i want to show the vehicle allocated time base on the time column. like if vehicle is already allocated at 10am, i want to show that in 10:00 column. Based on that user can see each vehicle availability. And can select vehicle if vehicle is not allocated at there required time.
I am using laravel framework
This is my controller function

```
$drivers = Driver::active()->get();
    foreach ($drivers as $key => $value) {
    $driver_allocation = DB::table('HELPDESK_TICKET')->select('*')
    ->whereDate('TRAVEL_DATE',$ticket->TRAVEL_DATE)
    ->where('STATUS',2)
    ->where('TICKET_DRIVER_ID',$value->DRIVER_ID)
    ->orderBy('TICKET_DRIVER_ID','ASC')->get();
        if($driver_allocation){
        $value->details = $driver_allocation;
    }else{
        $value->details = '';
    }
    }
    $vehicles = Vehicle::active()->get();
    foreach ($vehicles as $key => $value) {
        $vehicle_allocation = DB::table('HELPDESK_TICKET')->select('*')
        ->whereDate('TRAVEL_DATE',$ticket->TRAVEL_DATE)
        ->where('STATUS',2)
        ->where('TICKET_VEHICLE_ID',$value->VEHICLE_ID)
        ->orderBy('TICKET_VEHICLE_ID','ASC')->get();
        if($vehicle_allocation){
            $value->details = $vehicle_allocation;
        }else{
            $value->details = '';
        }
    }
```

View code

```
<table class="table align-items-center table-dark table-flush" id="datatable">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Vehicle</th>
                <?php 
            $a = '08:00';
            $b = '20:00';

            $period = new DatePeriod(
                new DateTime($a),
                new DateInterval('PT1H'),
                new DateTime($b)
            ); 
            foreach ($period as $date) {?>
                <th scope="col">{{$date->format("H:i\n")}}</th>
                <?php } ?>
        <tbody>
            <?php if($vehicles){
                foreach($vehicles as $vehicle){ ?>
            <tr id="item{{$vehicle->VEHICLE_ID}}">
                <td>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-3">
                        <input name="vehicle" class="custom-control-input"
                            id="customRadio{{$vehicle->VEHICLE_ID}}" type="radio"
                            value="{{$vehicle->VEHICLE_ID}}">
                        <label class="custom-control-label text-white"
                            for="customRadio{{$vehicle->VEHICLE_ID}}">{{$vehicle->VEHICLE_NAME}}</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <?php
                    foreach ($period as $date) { 
                    $nexthrs = $date->format("H:i\n"); 
                    $timestamp = strtotime($nexthrs) + 60*60;
                    $time = date('H:i', $timestamp);
                    if($vehicle->details){
                    foreach($vehicle->details as $detail){
                    $currentTime = (new DateTime(Carbon\Carbon::parse($detail->TRAVEL_DATE)->format('H:i')));
                    $startTime = new DateTime($nexthrs);
                    $endTime = (new DateTime($nexthrs))->modify('+1 hour');
                    if($currentTime >= $startTime && $currentTime <= $endTime) { 
                    ?>
                    <td>* {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($detail->TRAVEL_DATE)->format('H:i')}} <br>
                    {{$detail->TRAVEL_FROM.' - '.$detail->TRAVEL_TO}}</td>
                <?php } } } }?>
            </tr>
            <?php } } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Using the above code i got this view

[image]

My requirement is to display vehicle Prado allocated time 12:55 in 12 column, 18:30 in 18 column as below image

[image]

Can anyone help to solve this.

Comment: What data do you have in the database?

Comment: Also you queries can be changed to improve performance. You should be able to get data in one or two queries.

Comment: $drivers is not used anywhere so not relevant to the ticket.

Comment: After displaying vehicle view, same view will create for drivers

Answer (score 0):

Try changing part below:

```
foreach($vehicle->details as $detail){
 $currentTime = (new DateTime(Carbon\Carbon::parse($detail->TRAVEL_DATE)->format('H:i')));
 $startTime = new DateTime($nexthrs);
 $endTime = (new DateTime($nexthrs))->modify('+1 hour');
 if($currentTime >= $startTime && $currentTime <= $endTime) {
```

To

```
foreach($vehicle->details as $detail){
 $currentTime = Carbon\Carbon::parse($detail->TRAVEL_DATE);

 if($currentTime->betweenIncluded($nexthrs, $nexthrs->addHour()))
```